# Kubernetes- How to set up Ingress?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

```
 I have an application running on 1001. I deployed it to a container in port 80.
```

How can I use Ingress for that?
I tried using NodePort with --targetPort=1001 and and I added 80 in servicePort in `Ingress.yaml`.

kubectl expose deployment test --target-port=1001 --type=NodePort

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: test
    servicePort: 80
```

I am getting error

> Backend not found- 404

Am I using the correct way or should I need to follow something else?

Comment: An Ingress resource alone is not sufficient. You also need to deploy an Ingress controller, for example see https://daemonza.github.io/2017/02/13/kubernetes-nginx-ingress-controller/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup nginx ingress using helm from the official kubernetes charts repo at https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/tree/master/stable/nginx-ingress.

Along with the nginx ingress controller, you'll need an ingress resource too. Refer https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/complete-example for examples.

Comment: without nginx can't i use ingress?

Comment: @Ram nginx (https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/README.md) or GCE (https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/blob/master/README.md) can be used as an ingress in kubernetes (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#ingress-controllers)

Comment: @Ram Upvote and accept my answer if you think it is useful so that others know it is the right answer, thanks!

Comment: I have my environment in GKE. Still I need to do have controllers. If yes can you please provide some example. Please help me. It is much needed thing for me

Answer (score 0):

Finally It worked for me. Here are my findings

1) No need of nginx controllers if you are using GCE/GKE

2) PORTS:
If you are using container port `80` then service port should be `80`.

If the application is exposed to `4000` then NodePort

```
--port=80
--targetPort=4000
```

3) If you still see unhealthy status in Ingress. Check your path in health check it could be possible that you are not pointing the required.

Ex: I had to point to `/main.html in` `Request Path` of `LB*`

Comment: yeah, but be aware that if you want to automatically route http traffic to https you cannot use the gke controllers. you would need an nginx controller as ssl termination is not yet supported on gke.

Comment: How to add those controllers. Do i need to specify in Ingress.yaml or do i need to install? any reference will help a lot. (sample code)

Comment: which controllers exactly, if you are already running an ingress then it has a controller already.On google cloud, the default controller is "gce" and that is the one that does not support ssl termination. To use kubernetes inginx ingress you have to install it  using a couple of yaml files, here is a link that would help you: http://rahmonov.me/posts/nginx-ingress-controller/

Comment: _"No need of nginx controllers if you are using GCE/GKE"_ - This is correct. We can use either nginx _**or**_ CGE as the ingress controller per https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#ingress-controllers.

Comment: GKE Ingress load balancer support SSL termination these days.